# iPhone: read X chars from file

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I read X characters from file?
Not bytes.
What classes should help me?

The difficulty is that encoding is specified.

Comment: What's the difference between a byte and a "char"?

Comment: In UTF8, a character can be anywhere from 1 to 6 bytes.

Comment: Perhaps NSFileHanlde which allows seekToFileOffset and readDataLength.  Problem is that's bytes.  Maybe read worst case # of bytes for number of chars and then do NSString stringWithTF8Strings passing bytes???  Just guessing here

Comment: So I should handle a lot of encodings manually, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to read 1 byte and try to convert it to character. If exception occures, read 1 more byte anc try to convert... until reading 6 bytes or success.
On success append this character to string and read next bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I would read in the whole file into an `NSMutableString` if possible, then extract characters off the beginning as needed. If this is an option it'd be pretty simple to implement.

Comment: It's not possible: iOS devices have small amount of RAM(files are large).Also reading of chars can be mixed with reading of bytes.

Comment: Read into a small buffer and keep track of characters that way. Then memory is no longer an issue.

Comment: Well, it depends what you need then. Do you need "the 150,000th character in the file?" Do you need "the first 100 characters?" Do you need "the last 1,000,000 characters?" Each would probably have a different approach. Also, you said there was a known encoding; what is it? That will also affect the answer.

Comment: I'm writing file API for javascripts.  So I don't know what target developers will want. But I have specifications, and there is readXCharacters(x) method.

Comment: frontend is in JS((new File(path)).readXCharacters(x)), backend is in Objective C. Some kind of bridge.